# in jquery, how to make the right click of the mouse have the same behavior of left click

Tags: jquery

&lta id="link1" href="link1"&gtlink1&lt/a&gt

what i want to realize: when i right click or left click these link, i both go to the linked pages. I have several questions:

1. how can I get the href from jquery in firefox and IE?
2. how can I identify the mouse event in firefox and IE, the event.which has different behaivors in firefox and in IE

Thank you very much

Comment: Don't keep asking [the same question over again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316996/in-jquery-how-to-make-the-right-click-of-the-mouse-have-the-same-behavior-of-lef), update your previous question.

Answer (score 1):

To get the `href`, which is an attribute of the `a` tag, you can use

```
var the_href = $('#link1').attr('href');
```

This works on all major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#element').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
        alert('Left mouse button pressed');
        break;
        case 2:
        alert('Middle mouse button pressed');
        break;
        case 3:
        alert('Right mouse button pressed');
        $(this).click();
        event.preventDefault;
        break;
    }
});
```

(borrowed heavily from: [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-left-mouse-click-and-right-with-jquery))
I'm Not sure about the meaning of your #1

Adding @Camilo Díaz's answer to mine so you can have one complete answer to both your questions:
for #2: `var the_href = $('#link1').attr('href')`

My stated answer will accomplish your goal without needing the href attribute though.